# Schibboleth, um Angelsachsen (UK, US, Australien, Neuseeland) als Nichtdeutsche erkennen zu können?

Tags: spoken-language, accent

Ein [Schibboleth](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schibboleth) ist ein Wort oder ein Satz, den eine Sprachgruppe sehr einfach aussprechen kann, während eine andere Sprachgruppe dies überhaupt nicht hinbekommt.

In den Beispielen, die ich bisher gesehen habe, z.B. TV Tropes, wurden bisher nur Schibboleths verwendet, um Deutsche erkennen zu können, z.B. das berühmt-berüchtigte "Squirrel" (Einfach mal googlen).

Gibt es eigentlich auch umgekehrt deutsche Wörter, die Angelsachsen, die sonst akzentfrei Deutsch sprechen, nicht akzentfrei aussprechen können (und die evtl. sogar zeigen, aus welcher Gegend der Betreffende stammt)?

Comment: Man kann ohne weiteres beim Eichhörnchen bleiben und seinen Schwanz auf bairisch aussprechen. Außerhalb des süddeutsch/bairischen Sprachraums kriegt das keiner hin.

Comment: @tofro Oichhörnchenschwantz?

Comment: Das typische Beispiel ist das *Streichholzschächtelchen*.

Comment: Hier gibt's eine Dissertation zum *Oachkatzlschwoaf*: http://www.kleinberg.net/index_files/Page985.htm

Comment: Täusch' ich mich, oder wird nicht auch Müller eher "Miller" ausgesprochen? Dürfte für manche ähnliche Worte gelten, z.B. auch Genie, ("Jeannie"). Auch "Hamburger" und "Berlin" stellen sicher eine gewisse Hürde dar, wie oft redet  selbst ein z.B. in München lebender Amerikaner von den norddeutschen Stadteinwohnern statt von den Fleischeinlagen? A propos "München", auch nicht leicht, nehme ich an.

Comment: Meiner Erfahrung nach gibt es kaum ein Anglophon der sich nicht als solche abschleiert, wenn er den Mund öffnet und Deutsch redet. Mir ist es jedenfalls nie ein solcher begegnet, und Schibbolets sind folglich unnötig.

Comment: Gelten hier Lehnwörter aus dem Englischen als "deutsche Wörter"? Falls ja, könnte man einfach darauf achten, ob die Person zB "Job" mit einem deutschen, amerikanischen oder australischen Akzent ausspricht.

Comment: Wenn man den Schibboleth genauer betrachtet, gibt es mindestens drei Varianten:

Comment: 1. Schwer auszusprechende Lautkonstruktionen wie "squirrel" für Deutsche oder das "R" für manche Asiaten.

Comment: 2. Worte, die man in der eigenen Region einfach gewohnt ist, _anders_ auszusprechen wie wohl hauptsächlich in der Entstehungsgeschichte des Begriffes vorkommend. Hier gibt es eben für "Englisch vs. Deutsch" einige Ansatzpunkte für gemeinsame Wörter lateinischen Ursprungs wie unten von mir erwähnt mit "finite" sowie gegenseitige Lehnwörter o.ä. Gemeinsamkeiten stellen also m.E. also den historisch wohl häufigsten Trennungsansatz dar, ähnlich wie wenn man z.B. jugoslawische Sprachen unterscheiden wollte.

Comment: 3. Worte, die normal (nicht lautmalerisch) niedergeschrieben nicht genug Hinweise (für gewisse Sprachgruppen) liefern, _wie_ etwas auszusprechen ist, etwa ein Dialektbegriff eines hochdeutsch geschriebenen Wortes wie "Oachkatzlschwoaf" oder "Chuchichäschtli" [Küchenkästchen, schw.].

Comment: 4. Als gemeinsamen Unterpunkt für die drei erstgenannten Arten gibt es dann noch die erforderliche Aussprachegenauigkeit. Wenngleich ich z.B. als Hochdeutsch Sprechender trotzdem glaube, die beiden unter 3. genannten Dialektbegriffe hinreichend gut auszusprechen, wird mich ein Einheimischer aufgrund meiner Aussprache dennoch wohl als "nicht von hier" verorten können.

Comment: @Philm kannst Du diese Ausführungen bitte aus den Kommentaren retten und in eine deiner Antworten einbauen?

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu - Ich war mir nicht sicher, ob irgendjemand noch Interesse an meinen Ausführungen hatte. OK, mache ich. Gruß

Comment: @Philm Prima, vielen Dank. Ich bin mir sicher :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Tschechische Chefchemiker auf griechisch-chinesischen Passagierschiffen

..ist ein echter Hochdeutsch-Aussprache-Test, nicht spezifisch für englische Muttersprachler, aber auch für diese geeignet IMHO.

Anmerkung: Dass der Satz in vielen Dialekten oder Mundarten auch unterschiedlich ausgesprochen wird als im Hochdeutschen, schmälert in meinen Augen nicht dessen Eignung.

Anmerkung2: Für jemanden, der von Haus auch hochdeutsch spricht, ist das meines Erachtens auch kein Zungenbrecher, o.ä.

Drei Mundartvarianten fallen mir auf Anhieb ein: "kinesisch/Kemiker",  "schinesisch/Schemiker" und die Schwyzerdütsch-Variante des "ch".

Comment: Beantwortet die Frage nicht.

Comment: Das fragt aber nur das "ch" ab. Hilfreicher wäre es, auch noch die Umlaute ö und ü einzubauen.

Comment: @Carsten S. Doch, es ist ein Schibboleth, der verwendet werden kann, um Nichtdeutsche (sprachlich gesehen) zu identifizieren, auch Angelsachsen, die sonst gut Deutsch sprechen. So ist die Frage nämlich gestellt. Nochmal lesen. Klar wäre ein Satz, den NUR Angelsachsen schwer aussprechen können, die gewünschtere Antwort, aber die hat offenbar keiner.

Comment: Da anscheinend der ch-Laut im Deutschen besonders schwierig ist (Eichhörnchen, Frucht oder das oben erwähnte Streichholzschächtelchen habe ich auch noch gefunden ) akzeptiere ich das als Antwort. Während das jemand kaum 1:1 im Hochdeutschen genau so aussprechen wird, halte ich es für praktisch unmöglich, die Mundart, die den Satz (ver)formt, natürlich nachzuahmen.

Comment: Danke.. Aber: Wie? " kaum jemand"? Also ich bin in Hannover geboren und spreche das ohne Anstrengung oder Nachdenken hochdeutsch aus, ich empfinde es auch nicht als Zungenbrecher direkt. Ich dachte eigentlich, das wäre schon der "Normalfall"- außer natürlich, wenn jemand sehr mundartaffin ist.

Comment: Eichhörnchen ist nicht schwer. Das ch in lachen oder Nacht, das ist schwer. Zwei völlig verschiedene Laute. (Aber nur für "englische Muttersprachler" aus England ein Problem, nicht für jemanden von Wales). Andersrum ist "Loch Ness" ein interessanter Test.

Comment: @gnasher729: Danke, interessante Hinweise. Falls mehr Interesse wäre, könnte man für das "ch" gute Beispiele suche, z.B. "Wer nachts bei Loch Ness übernachtet, dem vergeht das Lachen."- Übrigens: Auf dict.cc gibt es zwei engl. Aussprachen für "Loch Ness", die amerikanische scheint mir davon, wie ich es als Deutscher ausspreche fast gar nicht entfernt, während die andere (British?) sich wie "Lock Ness" anhört- ist das so?

Comment: @Philm: Die Aussprachevarianten [ˈkineːs̬iʃ] und [ˈkeːmikɐ] (jeweils mit [k] als ersten Konsonanten) für »chinesisch« und »Chemiker« sind keine Mundartvarianten, sondern hochdeutsche Varianten. Im österreichischen Deutsch sind das sogar die einzigen richtigen Varianten. Gehe zu http://www.adaba.at und suche nach »Chemiker« bzw. »China« und lass dir die beiden Wörtern von den beiden österreichsichen Sprechern vorsprechen. (Ich erkenne beide österreichischen Sprecher an der Stimme. Beide sind ausgebildete Berufssprecher, der Mann, Peter Fichna, war sogar jahrelang Chefsprecher des ORF.)

Comment: Ich stimme Dir zu, konsequenterweise könnte man von einem österreichischen Hochdeutsch reden? Ist sicher ein schwieriges Thema, zumal da immer auch viel Anderes mitschwingt. Bezogen auf Deutschland, wenngleich ich kein Sprachwissenschaftler bin, wäre meine subjektive Zuordnung: "mit k" ist eine Mundart, das ist nichts Abwertendes, das ist wohl auch ein Problem bei der Ausdrucksweise- es hat auf jeden Fall nichts weniger "Hohes", da stimme ich definitiv zu.

Comment: Letzten Endes geht es hier ja um die Aufdeckung von Varianzen, nicht um deren Bewertung. Ich lerne beim Reisen oder Surfen gerne dazu. Nie hätte ich in der Schule für möglich gehalten, dass ich etwas "festhalten" solle, wenn mir jemand sagt, ich solle etwas "heben". Fast habe ich schon mal als Neuzugezogener etwas im falschen Stockwerk installiert, weil ich den 1. Stock nicht mit Erdgeschoß gleichgesetzt habe. Selten habe ich mich so als Ausländer in gefühlt, wie in Bayern als ich nicht die leiseste Idee hatte, was dieses "Fleischpflanzerl" sei. Usw. Unsere Sprache ist reich.

Answer (score 6):

Es gibt zwar in deutschen Dialekten eine ganze Menge Laute und Lautkombinationen, die für einen Fremdsprachler (und auch für manchen Deutschsprechenden aus anderen Regionen) schwer zu knacken sind, das Hochdeutsche verwendet aber meiner Meinung nach bereits ein "hinreichend verschliffenes Lautmuster", das ja von allen Deutschsprachlern gesprochen und verstanden werden muss.

Der Lackmustest für "native German" ist deshalb m.A. nach kein Aussprachetest, sondern ein Test auf die fliessende Verwendung eines Sprachmittels, das andere Sprachen in dieser Form nur unvollständig oder gar nicht besitzen:

Sowas könnte z.B. das komplexe Gender-System, die Artikel, oder, am besten, der Umgang mit Modalpartikeln, die andere Sprachen weniger ausgeprägt oder gar nicht besitzen. Hier liegt für mich ein fast 100% sicheres Unterscheidungskiterium zwischen "native speaker" und "guter Zweitsprachler".

Answer (score 3):

[Edit: Einleitung als Erklärung]

Wenn man den Schibboleth (erstmal nur wie gemeint hinsichtlich der Aussprache) genauer betrachtet, gibt es mindestens drei Varianten:

1. Schwer auszusprechende Lautkonstruktionen wie "squirrel" für Deutsche oder das "R" für manche Asiaten.
2. Worte, die man in der eigenen Region einfach gewohnt ist, anders auszusprechen. Dies ist wohl die Variante, die in der historischen Verwendung des Begriffes Schibboleth am häufigsten vorkommt. Letztendlich beruhen die Unterschiede also auf Verwandtschaft und/oder Nachbarschaft von Bevölkerungsgruppen, historischer, geographischer, sprachlicher. Hier gibt es eben für "Englisch vs. Deutsch" einige Ansatzpunkte für gemeinsame Wörter, z.B.  lateinischen Ursprungs, Lehnwörter, usw.

   - Ich habe in einer anderen Antwort Konstruktionen genannt, in denen die Schwierigkeit genau darin besteht, dass der Englische Muttersprachler bekannte Worte anders gewohnt ist, auszusprechen, z.B. "Hamburger", "finite", das gilt auch teilweise für gegenseitige Lehnwörter o.ä. Anders ausgedrückt: Gemeinsamkeiten wie Nachbarschaften historisch oder geografischer Natur stellen also m.E. den wohl häufigsten verwendeten Trennungsansatz dar, ähnlich wie wenn man z.B. jugoslawische Sprachen unterscheiden wollte.
3. Worte, die normal (nicht lautmalerisch) niedergeschrieben nicht genug Hinweise (für gewisse Sprachgruppen) liefern, wie etwas auszusprechen ist, etwa ein Dialektbegriff eines hochdeutsch geschriebenen Wortes wie das anderweitig erwähnte "Oachkatzlschwoaf" (bayerisch) oder "Chuchichäschtli" (Küchenkästchen, schwizerdütsch).
4. Als gemeinsamen Unterpunkt für die drei erstgenannten Arten gibt es dann noch die erforderliche Aussprachegenauigkeit. Wenngleich ich z.B. als Hochdeutsch Sprechender trotzdem glaube, die beiden unter 3. genannten Dialektbegriffe hinreichend gut auszusprechen, wird mich ein Einheimischer aufgrund meiner Aussprache dennoch wohl als "nicht von hier" verorten können.
5. Die Grundidee des Schibboleth lässt sich von der Aussprache aber auch auf Satzbaufehler u.ä., also allgemeine Schwierigkeiten, bestimmte Sätze oder Konstruktionen fehlerfrei zu sagen oder zu schreiben, übertragen, im folgenden ein Beispiel:

[Erste Antwort von mir- vor Edit:]
Da ein aussprachebezogener "echter" Schibboleth schwer zu finden scheint, [und nach obiger "Klassifikation"] stimme ich einer anderen Antwort zu, dass die Haupthürden im Deutschen meist woanders liegen als in der reinen Aussprache: Deswegen war meine erste ein "grammatischer Schibboleth" sozusagen (ich erlaube mir damit, dessen Bedeutung zu erweitern):

Wer selbst so einen Satz fehlerfrei formen oder auch nur unter ähnlichen Sätzen (z.B. in einem MC Test) sofort als korrekt erkennen kann , der ist, würde ich sagen, in einem deutschsprachigen Land geboren:

> Der Rock der zwei Mädchen war länger als die Hose des dritten Mädchens, der der BH zu groß war.

Oder auch einzeln, wenn auch deutlich leichter:
Die Männlichkeit, das Mädchen, die Hose, der Busen, der Rock

Comment: Beantwortet die Frage nicht.

Comment: Es gibt Fälle, wo eine Antwort einen stark verwandten Teilaspekt erwähnen kann. Ist sicher Geschmackssache, so wie auch die Notwendigkeit gewisser Kommentare.

Comment: Wow, mir war vorher gar nicht aufgefallen, dass beide Nichtantworten von Dir sind. Übrigens sind Unterscheidungen, die für Muttersprachler schwierig sind, nicht automatisch auf für Nicht-Muttersprachler schwer.

Comment: Hat niemand behauptet übrigens ;-) Und der Kommentar passt auch nicht zu dieser Antwort. Obiges ist ja gerade für Muttersprachler überhaupt nicht schwer..

Comment: Edit/Nachtrag: Vergleichbare Ideen: Ansonsten hatte mich mal ein Englischlehrer nach dem Unterschied zwischen "leiden an" und "leiden unter" gefragt. Tiefere Feinheiten wie den Unterschied zwischen dasselbe vs. das Gleiche oder der Verdienst vs. das Verdienst kriegen ja auch schon die meisten Deutschen nicht hin, das ist also für Ausländer erst recht zu schwer.

Answer (score 2):

Spezifisch für English native speakers:

> Johann Wolfgang von Goethe musste sich noch keine Gedanken über finite Elemente oder eine Integermatrix machen.

("finite" und "Integer" sind unerwartete Aussprache-Fallen- "fainaite" vs. "fieniete"- und meines Erachtens ziemlich gute Schibbolethe, aber auch Goethe dürfte nicht leicht für Jeden sein, der "Wulfgäng" insbesondere.)

Comment: Nachtrag: Ich selbst halte dies nachträglich für den besten genannten Schibboleth (von allen Antworten, insb. meinen :-) , aber ich hätte gerne Meinungen von English native speakern gehört..

Comment: Ich gebe hier zu bedenken, dass ich als deutscher Muttersprachler, der aber auch Softwareentwickler ist, das Nomen »Integer«, insbesondere vor den »Variablen«, nicht als deutsches Wort [ɪnˈteːɡɐ] sondern als englisches Wort [ˈɪnted͡ʒɐ] aussprechen würde, und ich glaube sogar, dass in diesem Kontext (»Integer Variable«) die englische Aussprache ohnehin die richtigere wäre. Außerdem ist die Schreibweise falsch: Es müsste »Integervariable« oder »Integer-Variable« heißen. Das Deppen-Leerzeichen ist im Deutschen kein erlaubtes Mittel zur Bildung von Komposita.

Comment: Du hast recht: Für einen Softwareentwickler ist das Wort deswegen kein guter Schibooleth, vielleicht ändere ich den Vorschlag noch ab, integer gibt es ja auch in anderen Kontexten. Insgesamt sehe ich bei Worten lateinischen Ursprungs, die es im Deutschen gibt, wenig Grund, eine englische Aussprache zu bevorzugen. Siehe auch  https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(Datentyp)

Comment: Lustig übrigens, dass Du zeitgleich meine Antworten hier kommentierst, während ich gerade dabei war, eine andere Frage von Dir umfangreich zu beantworten zu versuchen :-)

Comment: Mal allgemein: Das von Thema , ob z.B. **Softwareentwickler oder andere Profis auch deutsche Wörter oder Aussprachen verwenden**- ist sehr interessant- insbesondere müssen wir da alle unsere "Toleranz" erhöhen, dass es da auch große Unterschiede zwischen Deutschland/Österreich/Schweiz gibt, und sicher noch mehr unabhängig der Nationalitäten: Ich selbst bleibe, wenn ich deutsch rede, bei der deutschen Aussprache "Integer Variable" - und wenn ich Englisch rede oder extrem viele Englisch Begriffe vorkommen, dann spreche ich beides Englisch aus.

Comment: Ich kenne z.B. Schweizer Softwareentwickler, die wollten nicht glauben, dass bei uns in vielen dt. Firmen, auch von Softwareentwicklern, deutsche Windows-Versionen installiert werden (ich selbst habe beide Sprachen schnell umschaltbar und arbeite auch mit beiden Windows-Sprachen wechselnd, privat wie beruflich). Ähnlich für Office. VS dagegen selten in D, "admitted" :-) Oder ich hatte eine Meinungsverschiedenheit mit einem österreichischen Kollegen, ob der Begriff "serviceorientierte Architektur (SOA)" auch auf Deutsch verwendet wird bzw. verwendet werden darf und damit wikipediawürdig ist.

Comment: Wichtig finde ich: Nur weil dies in einem Land häufiger so oder anders herum ist, darf man nicht annehmen, dass dies für alle gilt.

Comment: geändert: Integervariable => Integer Matrix (aber egal für das Beispiel hier, das dt. Adjektiv "integer" sein gibt es ja auch- wenn es auch im Engl. nicht als Adjektiv verwendet wird ("to be of integrity".

Answer (score 1):

Variante aus der Klasse der Schibboleths der gemeinsamen und verwandten Worte- ein Versuch dies auf die Spitze zu treiben:

> Ernie Müller und sein Freund Bert Hamburger saßen in München und aßen eine Brezel, eine Portion Pommes Frites, zwei Hamburger und eine Nürnberger Bratwurst. Dabei lasen sie einen Reiseführer über Berlin.

(Ich kenne nicht genug gut Deutsch sprechende Angloamerikaner, um zu sagen, welche der gestellten Fallen am meisten Schwierigkeiten macht, aber alle Hauptwörter und Namen im Satz stellen eine Herausforderung dar, es gibt alle bis auf die "Pommes Frites" anders ausgesprochen im Englischen, wenn auch bei "Freund", "Müller" und "Brezel", "(..Führer)", "Nürnberger.." und "München" nur ähnlich/abgewandelt, was es aber nicht in allen Fällen unbedingt einfacher macht.)

--
Oder auch folgende kombinierte Lauthürden i/ü + diverse g Aussprachen:

> Bürger Berger ist deutscher Staatsbürger aus Hamburg, tanzt gerne Bergeretten und isst gerne Burger, während der Vater der heiligen St. Brigitta Birger hieß.

Haupthürden: Brigitta und Bergerette wird engl. mit "dsch" ausgesprochen.

Comment: Ich glaube eigentlich, dass es nicht viele Angloamerikaner gibt, die auch nur eines der Worte aus dem ersten Teil aussprechen wie ein Deutscher, aber in Summe wird das kaum möglich sein. Am Rande interessant ist, wie ein Deutscher jetzt "Hamburger" (das Essen) ausspricht, der "Burger" ist eindeutig englisch, aber ich spreche den "Hamburger" eigentlich deutsch aus wie die Stadt, den "Cheeseburger" eben englisch :-)

Comment: Das zweite wäre auch ein guter Kandidat für schriftlichen "Schiboleth", z.B. Multiple Choice Test, welche Abwandlung davon korrekt ist (Varianten mit ist/isst, usw.)